# How to get the number of found urls from icrawler without downloading

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler

I am using icrawler with python 3.5 to download images from Flickr, Bing, or Google. Now, I would like to compare the number of found image-urls without downloading the images.

If I understand the icrawler Documentation correctly, then the crawl method starts a Feeder, which puts all found urls in a queue. Therefore, it would be nice to have a function which gets the number of urls in the queue.

If there is no function for the icrawler package, it would be nice to get some suggestions for other crawler packages which have this function. I prefer Images from Flickr and Bing, because they support the CreativeCommons license.

I use icrawler as follows:

```
from icrawler.builtin import FlickrImageCrawler

flickr_crawler = FlickrImageCrawler(API_KEY, 
                                    storage={'backend': 'FileSystem', 'root_dir': cur_directory}
                                    )

flickr_crawler.crawl(max_num=10,
                     tags=keyword,
                     tag_mode = 'all',
                     sort = 'relevance',
                     license = '1,2,3,4,5'
                     )
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
flicker_crawler.feeder.in_queue.qsize()
```

but I'm not sure it's exactly what you want ( it's size of input queue of feeder )

Comment: While this line works I don't know where you can use it outside of your own crawler because while crawling feeders queue is changes in size and after it finishes it's 0. It puts urls in queue while downloading them so you can't get number of items to download before you start to crawl. At least using builtin Crawler classes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I add this before or after the flickr_crawler.crawl(...) method, your code gets always 0. I think, I have to overrite the crawl method, right? I'll try this tomorrow.

Comment: Seems that way, if you want to monitor progress while crawling you have to do it from inside Crawler of Feeder class.

Comment: It was way to hard for me. Now, I use the flickrapi package. For that I do:
    `import flickrapi` then
    `photos = flickr.walk(...)` and finally
    `len(photos)`
Actually, there can be None links in photos, so I have to remove them. However, this solution seems much easier. Nevertheless, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding, but can you just use len()?

```
len(task_queue)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can I get the queue?